# How to know if SonarQube has done post-analysis via API

Tags: sonarqube

I run a SonarQube scan on a Java maven project whith my Sonar server set as parameters.

But when the command line says it's done, it does not appear imediately on the SonarQube web UI nor via API. I need to wait from 1 to 3 minutes before the number of vulnerabilities increases.

I think there is a sort of post-analysis done when it's pushed to the server.
How can I know when this treatment is done ?

This is because I have another service that asks imediately the SonarQube API once the analysis is done on the machine, but it always returns 0 vulnerabilities since post treatment seems to not be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the scanning work is done, the report link is provided, but right after the scan completes, SonarQube initiates a "background task" that does some things that are somewhat opaque.  After that background task is complete, it is likely that your statistics are up to date.

Depending on how you run the scan, this "wait" is automatically managed for you.  For instance, if you use Jenkins pipelines, you should be using the "withSonarQubeEnv" and "waitForQualityGate" pipeline steps.  The latter goes into a wait loop, checking for the background task to be complete.  It is also possible to use the SonarQube "WebApi" RESt service, which can be used to get the status of the background task.  I would provide more info, but you haven't provided much info about the environment your scan is running in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually using GitLab Runners to complete my jobs only using Docker Images. So I have a SonarQube Docker image that runs the scan and is linked to our server. I can edit the entrypoint script to use the SonarQube API and ask if this background task is completed as you suggested. The next job I run needs to have the SonarQube analysis completed. 
Do you know which route should I call to get the background task status ?

Comment: You'll need to find the generated "report-task.txt" file, which will be in a Java properties file format, and get the "ceTaskId" property from it. Then do a GET for "/api/ce/task?id=$ceTaskId" from your sonarqube server host:port. That will give you a json block with a "task.status" property. That value will be SUCCESS, ERROR, PENDING, or IN_PROGRESS. The last two indicate it's not done yet.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems fairly easy to do, I will edit my script now